# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to0^+}\int_{ax}^{bx}\frac{\tanh y\cdot\tan^2y}{y^4}\,\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

I've came across an interesting exercise about calculus.

For all $x \neq 0$, let
$$ f(x) = \int_{ax}^{bx} \frac{\tanh y \cdot \tan^2 y}{y^4} \ \mathrm{d}y,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers. Then, the limit as $x \to 0^+$ is:

a) $0~~~$ b) $+\infty~~~$ c) undetermined$~~~$ d) $\ln(b/a)~~~$   e) $\arctan(b/a)$

I tried to solve it using integration by parts, but honestly, I couldn't find a good substitution. And if I did, the integral got much worse. To avoid this, I tried to find a relation within the fundamental theorem of calculus (judging by the look of those integration limits xD), and then I'm not sure if I can swap the limits (the one the question asks and the the limit of the derivative). I appreciate all the help or tips I can get.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since $x\to 0^+$, you can consider the expansion of the integrand function, keeping in mind that $\tanh y \sim y$ and $\tan y \sim y$:
$$\frac{\tanh y\tan^2y}{y^4}\sim \frac1y $$
Hence you have:
$$\int_{ax}^{bx}\frac1y\mathrm dy=\log (bx)-\log (ax)=\log(b/a) $$
**Edit**

As suggested in the comments, we have:
$$\frac{\tanh y\tan^2y}{y^4}=\frac1y+\frac y3+o(y) $$
so when taking the limit as $x\to 0^+$, the error goes to $0$.

Comment: It might be good to show that the error in $\sim$ leads to a term that indeed goes away in the limit $x\to 0^+$.

Answer (score 0):

Note
$$ f(x) = \int_{ax}^{bx} \frac{\tanh y \cdot \tan^2 y}{y^4} \ \mathrm{d}y\overset{t=\frac{y}{x}}=\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\tanh(tx) \cdot \tan^2(tx)}{t^4x^3} \ \mathrm{d}t.$$
Using
$$ \tan(x)=x+O(x^3), \tanh(x)=x+O(x^3) $$
one has
$$ f(x)=\int_a^b\frac 1t(1+O(t^2x^2))(1+O(t^2x^2))^2dt=\int_a^b\frac1t(1+O(t^2x^2))dt=\ln(b/a)+O(x^2) $$
and so
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\ln(b/a). $$

Comment: Equals? Surely that is not correct.

Comment: I forgot the limit.

Comment: Although it's fine for getting an answer to a multiple choice question, I would not give full credit for this on a mathematics exam.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I hope we can justify the passing of limit inside integral by showing that integrand $g(x, t) $ with $g(0,t)=1/t$ is continuous in $[0,h]\times[a,b]$.

Comment: It’s not hard to justify it.

Answer (score 0):

The OP attempted to evaluate the limit using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  We now proceed to adopt this approach.

Let $F(a,b)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\int_{ax}^{bx}\frac{\tanh(y)\tan^2(y)}{y^4}\,dy$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F(a,b)}{\partial b}&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\frac{\tanh(bx)\tan^2(bx)}{(bx)^4}\\\\
&=\frac1b\tag1
\end{align}$$

and similary

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F(a,b)}{\partial a}&=-\frac1a\tag2
\end{align}$$

Integrating $(1)$, we find that $F(a,b)=\log(b)+G(a)$, where $G$ is a function of $a$ only. Then $(2)$ implies that $G'(a)=-1/a$, which reveals that $G(a)=-\log(a)+C$, where $C$ is a constant that we will determine.

To find $C$, note that F(a,a)=0=C$.

Putting it all together, $F(a,b)=\log(b/a)$.  And we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. ;-)